# setAlpha() not working for buttons within Fragment lifecycle functions (Android)

Tags: android, button, fragment, lifecycle

In one fragment in my application, a simple private method controls whether the "submit" button is activated or not:

```
private void activateSubmitButton(boolean activate){
    if (activate){
        submit.setClickable(true);
        submit.setAlpha((float)1);
    }else{
        submit.setClickable(false);
        submit.setAlpha((float)0.5);
    }
}
```

The Button object is created inside the OnCreateView() function of the Fragment:

```
submit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.newdutch_acceptbutton);
```

This is the button in question in the layout:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/newdutch_acceptbutton"
   android:text="ACCEPT"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@style/acceptbutton"/>
```

**My problem is the following:** The default state of the button should be deactivated when the Fragment is created. In order to do this, the **activateSubmitButton(FALSE)** method is called from the onCreateView() method. However, the setAlpha() function doesn't work when it is called from any of the lifecycle methods of the Fragment. I've tried moving it inside the OnResume() method with no success.

This method **activateSubmitButton()** is called from many places in the Fragment's code, however. For example, when the user has filled all the boxes, the button's alpha is set to (float)1, and when the user erases one of the boxes, it goes back to (float)0.5. In these instances, everything works as it should.

What could be happening?

Comment: IMO it should work right after you initialise the `submit` button in the `onCreateView()` itself

Comment: so, the setClickable always works, but not alpha?

Comment: Can you show us the "style.xml" file where you have defined the `acceptbutton`style?

Comment: <style name="acceptbutton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/progressgreen</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>

    </style>

Comment: Post your whole Fragment.